# how can i get just title from this json array? (javascript/discord.js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, discord.js

how can I get "title" from this json array in javascript? I want to get all of "title"s from this json array and put them into another array like **this :**

```
array(
`hey title1`,
`hey title2`,
...
)
```

but I don't know how many titles we are going to get and i think it's possible with for

```
    {
  data: [
    {
      id: '46475273517',
      user_name: 'testtwo',
      title: 'Hello this is my test for the eJx2',
      is_set: true
    },
    {
      id: '46471542013',
      user_name: 'testone',
      title: 'Hello this is my test for the eJx3',
      is_set: false
    },
    {
      id: '46474254233',
      user_name: 'testthree',
      title: 'Hello this is my test for the eJx7',
      is_set: false
    }
  ],
  pagination: {
    cursor: 'eyJiIjp7IkN1cnNvciI6ImV5SnpJam80TXpBeExqSTBNemcwTVRnME56WTVOQ3dpWkNJNlptRnNjMlVzSW5RaU9uUnlkV1Y5In0sImEiOnsiQ3Vyc29yIjoiZXlKeklqbzFOREV1T1RnMk56STNNall5TkRReE5Dd2laQ0k2Wm1Gc2MyVXNJblFpT25SeWRXVjkifX0'
  }
}
```

**thank you for your help**

Comment: `yourObject.data.map(el => el.title);`

Comment: Please try: `const titleArray = obj?.data?.map(({ title }) => title) ?? [];` and share feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var arry = {
    data: [ { id: '46475273517', user_name: 'testtwo', title: 'Hello this is my test for the eJx2', is_set: true }, { id: '46471542013', user_name: 'testone', title: 'Hello this is my test for the eJx3', is_set: false }, { id: '46474254233', user_name: 'testthree', title: 'Hello this is my test for the eJx7', is_set: false } ], pagination: { cursor: 'eyJiIjp7IkN1cnNvciI6ImV5SnpJam80TXpBeExqSTBNemcwTVRnME56WTVOQ3dpWkNJNlptRnNjMlVzSW5RaU9uUnlkV1Y5In0sImEiOnsiQ3Vyc29yIjoiZXlKeklqbzFOREV1T1RnMk56STNNall5TkRReE5Dd2laQ0k2Wm1Gc2MyVXNJblFpT25SeWRXVjkifX0' } } 

var titles = arry.data.map((item) => {
        return {
           id: item.id,
           title: item.title
        }
    })
```

here is a simple one i added the id property to know which ones title it is